# css3 rotateX creates a line

Tags: javascript, css, transform, css-transforms, rotatetransform

[image]

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/98otxxwm/12/)

Why is this white line visible?
It is not actually white, but just shows the background of the site, which happens to be white.

This won't take place when using a background-image instead of a color for the rotating divs.

Using this to apply the rotation:

```
$('.box').css('transform', 'translateZ(-'+halfHeight+'px) rotateX('+ deg +'deg)')
```

Comment: It feels like a browser artifact. It certainly doesn't happen in my PC (Firefox 49 x64 on Windows 10)

Comment: Does not happen on Chrome (Windows) 53.0.2785.116 either.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the graphic renderer. And, it won't be the same in all computers.

My suggestion, instead of using `translateZ()` use `translate3d()`, this will use the GPU when available and the animation will be smooth without any frame drop.

More read at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d)

Comment: Yeah, I can replace `transladeZ` and `rotateX` for `translate3d` and `rotate3d` respectively, but that won't solve the issue anyway. https://jsfiddle.net/98otxxwm/14/

Comment: @Alvaro It'll force the system to use the GPU instead of the CPU which may fix this

Comment: just a note... translateZ enables the 3d engine. Z axis lies in 3d space.